# Python get N elements from a list at a time using lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda

Imagine I have a list like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Using a lambda function, I would like to return two elements at a time, so the result would be:

```
res = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to use lambda? Is this homework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.izip(a, itertools.islice(a,1,None))
```

This avoids creating a copy of your original list, which may be relevant if it's very big.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> zip(a, a[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

For arbitrary `n`:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> zip(*(a[i:] for i in range(n)))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> map(lambda i:a[i:i+2], range(len(a)-1))
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: identical to my other answer (which I just deleted). +1 for using the lambda he asked for

Comment: although it's being asked, that's a pretty bad use of lambda.

Comment: @JBernardo, I guess the bonus is that it works with Python1.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a generator.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>>  g=([a[i:i+2]] for i in range(len(a)-1))
```

you can always grab the list if you want:

```
>>> list(g)
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[a[i:i+2] for i in range(len(a)-1)] # => [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```