# how to cut a serial numbers into intervals in python code?

Tags: python, r

Cut divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x according to which interval they fall.i can get small groups with cut function in R,how can i do the same 
job in python code ?

```
raw_data='
82   68   86   94   89   63   77   76   84    89
75   78   81   82   76   99   80   84   89    88
60   83   72   83   85   56   86   68   75   100
90   84   75   86   74   77   95   63   80    76
100   43  76   81   79   74   96   52   69    86'
data<-scan(textConnection(raw_data)) 
table(cut(data,include.lowest=TRUE,right=FALSE,breaks=c(0,60,70,80,90,100))
```

The output is :

```
[0,60)  [60,70)  [70,80)  [80,90) [90,100] 
   3        6       14       20        7
```

Comment: If you use Pandas, there is a similar cut function there as well. Otherwise, why not just implement it yourself?

Comment: When i draw graph with the python library--matplotlib ,it is more lines(about 3 times) to do the same thing than R ,but python is more logical than R,maybe it is a good try to do statistics with python.

Comment: Looking at your comments on the answers - are you using Python 3.x here?

Comment: Thank you for your acceptance of my answer. This was the occasion for me to remind that I wasn't entirely satisfied of my answer, and I've posted just now an improved version of my code.

Comment: @sus_mlm : what is the function name in pandas ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature : just "cut". http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this code:

```
raw_data='''
82   68   86   94   89   63   77   76   84    89
75   78   81   82   76   99   80   84   89    88
60   83   72   83   85   56   86   68   75   100
90   84   75   86   74   77   95   63   80    76
100   43  76   81   79   74   96   52   69    86'''
tu = (0,60,70,80,90,100)

print raw_data
print tu

from collections import OrderedDict
tu0 = tu[0]
tuL = tu[-1]
tuF = tu[1:]
d = OrderedDict((tu[i], [tu[i-1:i+1]])
                for i in xrange(1,len(tu)))

for x in map(int,raw_data.split()):
    if x>=tu0:
        if x==tuL:
            d[tuL].append(x)
        else:
            for lim in tuF:
                if x<lim:
                    d[lim].append(x)
                    break
print
print '\n'.join('%-15s%s' % (d[k][0],len(d[k])-1) for k in d)
```

result

```
(0, 60)        3
(60, 70)       6
(70, 80)       14
(80, 90)       20
(90, 100)      7
```

.

#### EDIT

I wasn't satisfied of all these `if`, `for`, `else` and `break` in the algorithm.
So I give a new code, I think it is an improvement because it is shorter and clearer. I think it is also faster, but I didn't test the speed.

The difficulty was that when a number in raw_data is equal to the last value (100 in the sample) of the sequence of limits `tu = (0,60,70,80,90,100)` , this number must be counted as belonging to the last span , here `[90,100]` (mathematics' notation) in the sample, while the preceding spans like `[0,60[` , `[60,70[` ... are with non included upper limit.
But I finally found the correct test `x==tuLast==lim` to hold this particular case, then being able to use a generator instead of the horrid former algorithm with several tests `if` and a loop.

The following code is executable in Python 3.

```
raw_data='''
82   68   86   94   89   63   77   76   84    89
75   78   81   82   76   99   80   84   89    88
60   83   72   83   85   56   86   68   75   100
90   84   75   86   74   77   95   63   80    76
100   43  76   81   79   74   96   52   69    86'''
tu = [0,60,70,80,90,100]
print( 'raw_data :%s\n\ntu :\n%s' % (raw_data,tu),'\n' )
    
tu0, tuLast = tu[0], tu[-1]
tu_from1 = tu[1:]
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict( (two[1],[two]) for two in zip(tu, tu_from1) )

print ('OrderedDictionary , before:\n%s'
       % '\n'.join('key:%3s   value:%s'  % item for item in d.items()))

# the core of the code is here:
for x in (x for x in map(int,raw_data.split()) if x>=tu0):
    d[next(lim for lim in tu_from1
           if x<lim or x==tuLast==lim)].append(x)

print ('\nOrderedDictionary , after:\n%s'
       % '\n'.join('key:%3s   value:%s'  % item for item in d.items()),'\n')

print( '\n'.join('%-15s%s' % (v[0],len(v)-1) for v in d.values()) )
```

result

```
raw_data :
82   68   86   94   89   63   77   76   84    89
75   78   81   82   76   99   80   84   89    88
60   83   72   83   85   56   86   68   75   100
90   84   75   86   74   77   95   63   80    76
100   43  76   81   79   74   96   52   69    86

tu :
[0, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] 

OrderedDictionary , before:
key: 60   value:[(0, 60)]
key: 70   value:[(60, 70)]
key: 80   value:[(70, 80)]
key: 90   value:[(80, 90)]
key:100   value:[(90, 100)]

OrderedDictionary , after:
key: 60   value:[(0, 60), 56, 43, 52]
key: 70   value:[(60, 70), 68, 63, 60, 68, 63, 69]
key: 80   value:[(70, 80), 77, 76, 75, 78, 76, 72, 75, 75, 74, 77, 76, 76, 79, 74]
key: 90   value:[(80, 90), 82, 86, 89, 84, 89, 81, 82, 80, 84, 89, 88, 83, 83, 85, 86, 84, 86, 80, 81, 86]
key:100   value:[(90, 100), 94, 99, 100, 90, 95, 100, 96] 

(0, 60)        3
(60, 70)       6
(70, 80)       14
(80, 90)       20
(90, 100)      7
```

Comment: when i run `d = OrderedDict((tu[i], [tu[i-1:i+1]])
                for i in xrange(1,len(tu)))` ,NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined.

Comment: What I think to is that you use Python 3 in which there is no more ``xrange``, only ``range``. But if so, you should obtain on the preceding instructions with ``print`` that need parentheses, since ``print()`` is nowadays a function in Python 3

Comment: I've just seen that you worry about ``izip`` and ``imap`` concerning the other answers. This convinces me that you use Python 3 in which ``map`` is now a generator and ``zip`` too

Answer (score 1):

As sus_mlm suggested you can use Pandas for this. But if you want to avoid an external import and `raw_data` isn't too large, you could use:

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

# 'kwargs' lets you implement more options
def cut ( data, breaks, **kwargs ):
    counts = Counter()
    ranges = itertools.izip(breaks, itertools.islice(breaks,1,None))
    for element in data:
        for range in ranges:
            if range[0] < element < range[1]:
                counts[range] += 1
                break
    return counts

# Call 'cut'
cut( raw_data, (0,60,70,80,90,100) )
```

[Acknowledgements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727623/python-get-n-elements-from-a-list-at-a-time-using-lambda)

Comment: You might want to double check this... I'm fairly sure you should be using `breaks` instead of `data` for `ranges = `... However, since you're using `izip` this means `ranges` will be exhausted after the first element in data is processed, which means that for the 2nd item onwards the `for range in ranges` is a no-op.

Comment: That's one thing fixed, but the output is: `Counter({(77, 95): 1, (68, 94): 1})`

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bisect` to get the "range" it falls into and a `defaultdict` as a counter for occurrences in each range, eg:

```
from bisect import bisect
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain, imap

raw_data="""
82   68   86   94   89   63   77   76   84    89
75   78   81   82   76   99   80   84   89    88
60   83   72   83   85   56   86   68   75   100
90   84   75   86   74   77   95   63   80    76
100   43  76   81   79   74   96   52   69    86""".lstrip()

# Make data into iterable of ints
data = chain.from_iterable(
    imap(int, line.split()) 
    for line in raw_data.splitlines()
)
# Counter
count = defaultdict(int)
for num in data:
    # Use 101 instead of 100 to cater for inclusion of 100
    count[bisect([0, 60, 70, 80, 90, 101], num)] += 1
```

Results in `count` being:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 14, 4: 20, 5: 7})
```

Comment: when i run ,`NameError: global name 'imap' is not defined`.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature if you're using Python 3.x - drop the `imap` from the import at the top and change the line starting `imap(int...)` to just be `map` instead. I'm not sure why you're getting that error, as if you're using Python 3.x, you should be getting an `ImportError` instead... (However, your other comments seem to be consistent that you're possibly using 3.x)...